# Inconsistency in indentation warnings

Tags: f#

I find F# somewhat inconsistent about its indentation warnings, here's an example from some code I was recently writing:

```
// Weird: F# complains with FS0058 about d2dDevice here
use d2dContext = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext(
    d2dDevice, SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContextOptions.None)

// But not about d2dContext here
d2dContext.Target <- new Bitmap1(
    d2dContext,
    backBuffer,
    BitmapProperties1(
        PixelFormat(
            SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied),
        96.f, 96.f, BitmapOptions.Target ||| BitmapOptions.CannotDraw))
```

Is there a logical reason why the latter is correct indentation but not the former?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is all defined in the spec - from 15.1.4 in the spec for F# 3.1:

> Lightweight syntax is sometimes called the  “offside rule”. In F#
>   code, offside lines occur at column positions. For example, an = token
>   associated with let introduces an offside line at the column of the
>   first non-whitespace token after the = token.

Later on, we see the rule for `<-`

> immediately after a <- token is encoutered when the subsequent token
>   either (a) does not occur on the same line or (b) is one of try,
>   match, if, let, for, while or use.

We note that in your case, the subsequent token (new) is on the same line and isn't from the list so there is no offside line.

Essentially `=` has different rules compared to `<-`